# (API) Finding an opportunity's "Project start date" and "Project end date"

Tags: soap-api, opportunity

I'm creating a script that continuously pushes back an opportunity's close date to be greater than 2 months, and the project start date and project end date to be greater than 1 month.

I'm able to completely interact with the API and get the opportunity data ([source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm)), but I'm not able to find the data for the fields labeled as "Project start date" and "Project end date", as shown in the lightning dashboard interface:

[image: example of dashboard data]

Tl;dr; This data isn't returned by the API on an Opportunity object, so how do I find (and modify) this data?

Comment: Do you have FLS to those fields?

Comment: Dealing with Salesforce is very new to me. I have permission to edit the data via the lightning interface (which I assume meant I should be able to read and write the data other ways), and I'm not sure how editing FLS works

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer by digging around the Metadata APIs. "Project Start Date" and "Project End Date" are just labels, and the field that holds that data has a different name entirely.

Project End Date is `Last_Payment_Date_End_of_Payment_Sched__c` 
Project Start Date is `Project_Start_Date_Invoice_Date__c`

[image: Terminal output of helper that got the API field from a user-friendly name]